# How to contain a horizontal and a vertical list in the same screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to have a horizontally scrollable list at the top and a vertically scrollable list beneath it. I tried different combinations but they are not working or they make the app crash. How can I achieve such a screen?

Comment: Can you provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scaffold
  Container height mediaquery height, width - mediaquery width
    SingleChildScrollView
      Column(with mainAxisSize.min)
        SingleChildScrollView(direction Axis.horizontal)
            Row()
        Add other elements that you wish to show below the horizontal scroll.
```

If you are using ListView builder don't forget to add shrink wrap true.